# Breaking long section titles in table of contents

Tags: latex

Is it possible to tune LaTeX to break automatically long (sub-) section titles in the table of contents?

Answer (score 12):

You can manually set the title that appears in the TOC like this:

```
\section[Lorem ipsum]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
```

That way the "long title" appears on the section itself, and the "short title" appears in the TOC.  I haven't tried it, but it might be possible to use the same number of words in the square brackets but insert manual line-breaks with `\\`.

Comment: Use \newline instead of \\: some document classes, such as memoir, will lay out \\ badly in the document body's section heads.